# Javascript: Variable value never changed in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

This is the code:

```
 var link, summary;
 for (var i = 0; i < json.cards[0].widgets.length; i++) {
    link = json.cards[0].widgets[i].text;
    var params = {
        // various parameters
    };
    var req = http.request(params, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            summary = JSON.parse(data.toString()).content;
            // Now, the process method takes "summary" correctly, 
            // but "link" is always the same, hence, not changing 
            // on every other cycle.
            process(summary, link);
            // That's how it would look if looped 3 times
            // process('positive', 'http://www.google.com/blah');
            // process('negative', 'http://www.google.com/blah');
            // process('neutral', 'http://www.google.com/blah');
        });
    });
    req.end();
 }
```

As I commented in the code, `link` never changes, it takes the first value, then `process()` takes the same value of `link` all the time, while `summary` is always different, which is expected.

Comment: Those HTTP requests are **asynchronous**. The outer loop will finish basically immediately after starting up all the requests. When the request callbacks finally happen, the value of `link` will be whatever it was on the last iteration.

Comment: You can separate the request into a function and pass `link` as a parameter of that function

Comment: @AlonEitan, I did what you suggested and it works. Could you please make it an answer? I will accept the answer.

Comment: For others, thanks a lot for the info, the infos are very valuable!

Comment: @SamKirklandWA That's fine, you can self-answer your question. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alon Eitan helped me out by suggesting to separate it in a separate function and it worked. That's how my code looks now:

```
 var link, summary;
 for (var i = 0; i < json.cards[0].widgets.length; i++) {
    link = json.cards[0].widgets[i].text;
    var params = {
        // various parameters
    };
    var sent = function(link, params){
        var req = http.request(params, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                summary = JSON.parse(data.toString()).content;
                process(summary, link);
            });
        });
        req.end();
    }
    sent(link, params);
 }
```

Comment: For the sake of best practice, I will mention that defining a function within a loop is less-than-optimal. You can define your function outside the loop and just call it with the same parameters and that way you don't redefine the function for every iteration of the loop - saves memory & cpu cycles.

Answer (score 1):

`req` is an asynchronous function, so there is no guarantee regarding what order it will return in with comparison to the outer loop. As such, it's almost certain in this case that the outer loop finishes before the request even returns, so `link` is always the same.

Instead of doing this, try using `promises`, or pass the value of `link` as a parameter to the request so that it will have the right value for each return.